# Password protected PDF using C#

Tags: c#, pdf-generation

I am creating a pdf document using C# code in my process. I need to protect the docuemnt 
with some standard password like "123456" or some account number. I need to do this without 
any reference dlls like pdf writer.

I am generating the PDF file using SQL Reporting services reports.

Is there are easiest way.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> I am creating a pdf document using C#
>   code in my process

Are you using some library to create this document? The [pdf specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) (8.6MB) is quite big and all tasks involving pdf manipulation could be difficult without using a third party library. Password protecting and encrypting your pdf files with the free and open source [itextsharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/) library is quite easy:

```
using (Stream input = new FileStream("test.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
using (Stream output = new FileStream("test_encrypted.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(input);
    PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(reader, output, true, "secret", "secret", PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING);
}
```

Comment: Note that itextsharp requires a license for commercial use, unless your code is also released under the same license it uses. Prices only available upon application.

Comment: Further note that this answer was written in 2008, at which time iTextSharp was released under the LGPL. Upon the release of version 5.0.0 (Dec. 2009, SVN revision 108; license change is at revision 99), the license was changed to AGPL, requiring Application Service Providers to either release source code or purchase a commercial license. The previous version (4.1.6; LGPL) is forked [here](https://github.com/itextsharper/iTextSharp-4.1.6) and still has the above functionality.

Comment: It's a shame that this encrypt is too easy to break. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31493/PDF-Security-Remover

Answer (score 1):

It would be very difficult to do this without using a PDF library. Basically, you'll need to develop such library yourselves.

With help of a PDF library everything is much simpler. Here is a sample that shows how a document can easily be protected using [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/):

```
public static void protectWithPassword(string input, string output)
{
    using (PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(input))
    {
        // set owner password (a password required to change permissions)
        doc.OwnerPassword = "pass";

        // set empty user password (this will allow anyone to
        // view document without need to enter password)
        doc.UserPassword = "";

        // setup encryption algorithm
        doc.Encryption = PdfEncryptionAlgorithm.Aes128Bit;

        // [optionally] setup permissions
        doc.Permissions.CopyContents = false;
        doc.Permissions.ExtractContents = false;

        doc.Save(output);
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I work for the vendor of the library.

Comment: is this library free or not?

Comment: @AkalankaEkanayake The library [can be free](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/free-pdf-library.aspx) in certain cases but in general case you woul need to pay for the license.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for a IText7 reference.

```
    private string password = "@d45235fewf";
    private const string pdfFile = @"C:\Temp\Old.pdf";
    private const string pdfFileOut = @"C:\Temp\New.pdf";

public void DecryptPdf()
{
        //Set reader properties and password
        ReaderProperties rp = new ReaderProperties();
        rp.SetPassword(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(password));

        //Read the PDF and write to new pdf
        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFile, rp))
        {
            reader.SetUnethicalReading(true);
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(reader, new PdfWriter(pdfFileOut));
            pdf.GetFirstPage(); // Get at the very least the first page
        }               
}
```