# How to create password protected pdf using itextsharp?

Tags: asp.net

I m creating pdf dynamically.So while creating itself i need to protect it with password.
I m using asp.net,c#,and for pdf itextsharp.

This is my code

using (Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4,0f,0f,0f,0f))
            {

```
            string path = Server.MapPath("Pages");

            FileStream pdffile= new FileStream(path+"/Pdf/tes.pdf", FileMode.Create);
            PdfWriter writer=PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc,pdffile);
            doc.Open();
            var titlefont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 16, Font.BOLD);   
            doc.Add(new Paragraph("My Pdf",titlefont));
            doc.Close(); 

            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=tes.pdf"); 
            Response.TransmitFile(path+"/Pdf/tes.pdf");                  
            Response.Flush();
            File.Delete(path + "/Pdf/tes.pdf");
                        }
```

Thanks..

Comment: possible duplicate of [iTextSharp Password Protected PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586346/itextsharp-password-protected-pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I searched for other topics and this seems to be working for this guy:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6586551/1648976

Hope it helps you.