# iTextSharp - Password Protect PDF's

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, itext

I am using following code to generate `PDF's`. I want to `password protect` the PDF.

How to Password Protect PDF's in `iTextSharp`?

```
document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 25, 25);
output = new MemoryStream();
writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);

document.Open();    
document.Add(OuterTable);    
document.Close();    

System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/PDFs/" + name.ToString() + ".pdf"), output.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PdfEncryptor. The `userPassword` arg will set a password on it. http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfEncryptor.html

Comment: I am confused about the first parameter for the method `PdfEncryptor.Encrypt()`. What should i pass to it?

Comment: Here's an example of someone using it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586346/itextsharp-password-protected-pdf