# Password protecting a PDF file

Tags: c#

I have the following:

- routine X that creates a PDF file on a daily basis.
- routine Y that attaches this file to an Outlook e-mail and sends it to recipients.

Both the above are in VBA. They are called from a C# console application.

Once the PDF has been created I need to password protect it. 
To do this via VBA without purchasing third party software is quite involved.

What is the simplest solution using C#?

(I'm suspecting there will be an inverse relationship between amount we spend and complexity of answer!)

Comment: If you only need to password protect your pdf file then use http://itextpdf.com/ library. For more info goto this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370571/password-protected-pdf-using-c-sharp

Comment: @DarshanJoshi: iText is not free for commercial use.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth two people have voted to close this question - I've tried to be very specific; are there any possible edits I can make to make it more acceptable?

Comment: @whytheq: I was one of the persons voting to close the question. My reason was that there wasn't a concrete problem. You asked for general guidance. I never did PDF editing - my answer is the result of five minutes of googling. You could have done this yourself.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I think a lot of people use SO for a first port of call so to keep this question open isn't a bad thing as your answer is good and concise i.e Google can be avoided. Although I suspect I'll have more code specific questions when implementing your answer so the code will still end up on here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @whytheq: No need to avoid google - it can be used to find answers faster than using SO.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I use Google all the time; I also get the feeling SO is turning into a massive stand alone resource.

Comment: @whytheq: Indeed, it is. A lot of my google searches end up here :-)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Q.E.D ...pass go on Google and come straight to SO

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/) should be able to protect a PDF file with a password:

```
// Open an existing document. Providing an unrequired password is ignored.
PdfDocument document = PdfReader.Open(filename, "some text");

PdfSecuritySettings securitySettings = document.SecuritySettings;

// Setting one of the passwords automatically sets the security level to 
// PdfDocumentSecurityLevel.Encrypted128Bit.
securitySettings.UserPassword  = "user";
securitySettings.OwnerPassword = "owner";

// Don't use 40 bit encryption unless needed for compatibility reasons
//securitySettings.DocumentSecurityLevel = PdfDocumentSecurityLevel.Encrypted40Bit;

// Restrict some rights.
securitySettings.PermitAccessibilityExtractContent = false;
securitySettings.PermitAnnotations = false;
securitySettings.PermitAssembleDocument = false;
securitySettings.PermitExtractContent = false;
securitySettings.PermitFormsFill = true;
securitySettings.PermitFullQualityPrint = false;
securitySettings.PermitModifyDocument = true;
securitySettings.PermitPrint = false;

// Save the document...
document.Save(filename);
```

Reference:
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/ProtectDocument-sample.ashx

Comment: this looks good & relatively simple - is it totally open source? i.e even for commercial use it is free?

Comment: @whytheq: [Yes](http://www.pdfsharp.net/Licensing.ashx), it is free to use even in commercial products.

Comment: had a play this afternoon - excellent; I've imported all the source code folders...even had a little nose through the source code!

Comment: @whytheq: Cool :-) I want to point out that it would have been enough to reference the compiled assembly from your code.

Comment: ok added this subsequent [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391244/pdfsharp-getting-started) and the PdfSharp team answered; they seem to favour importing all the folders. I think they mentioned that it adds intellisense. For me, as a c# newbie, i enjoyed adding the projects as it gave me a sense of what is actually being used when I put `using x` at the top of a code module; a reference seems a little more black-box.

Comment: @whytheq: You can have intellisense without adding the project. Simply place the pdfsharp.dll.xml file beside the pdfsharp.dll.

Comment: thanks - not sure of the reason then why the pdfsharp team suggest importing the projects. When I add a reference using VS what does it do? - just physically move a copy of the `.dll` file into the project/solution? ...I could effectively just use import existsing item and go and find the dll and bring it into the project; would be equivalent to using the references? Or is adding a reference just a pointer to somewhere else on my machine?

Comment: @whytheq: Maybe you should ask that as a new question. It seems like you are missing some basics here :-) Others are better at explaining basics than I am...

Comment: hmmm - I am still learning the basics. basic questions can sometimes be hounded out of SO - I might be better Googling. thanks for all the help on this question.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth can this document be opened in PdfSharp after password protection is applied..? if not, how we are gonna load this document again..?

Comment: @harsh: It should be supported. The sample I posted already hints at it: *// Open an existing document. **Providing an unrequired password is ignored**.*

Comment: @DanielHilgarth- So is there a way we can make password a required thing to open the document..?

Comment: @harsh: Yes, sure. Not clear what you are asking here or what your problem is. My answer shows how to password protect a PDF file. The second parameter to `PdfReader.Open` is the passwort needed to open a password protected PDF file. If you have any further questions, please post them as such if they haven't been answered already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 2):

**For .NET Core/.NET 5 and up only**

---

[PdfSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/) works only on **old .NET Framework**.
[PdfSharpCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PdfSharpCore) is the same library just ported to the new **.NET (.NET Core)**.

The above [answer by @Daniel Hilgarth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12383598/4390133) still works without any change to the code with the ported library.

**NOTE** This library is under [MIT LICENSE](https://github.com/ststeiger/PdfSharpCore/blob/master/LICENSE.md), so nothing to worry about.